# How can I extract data from windows application running on my pc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, extract

I would like to know if there is any method to exctract data from a windows application running ?

To explain I have a game on my pc and i would like to see what change when for example Pacman what's the data of the game before eating a pacgum and after.

The objective is to save it and compare them at another moment and check the changed values (score, pacgum, etc...)

I search a lot of article but i only found webscrapping or thing like this but in my part it's local app running on my computer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You could use [cheat engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_Engine). Which scans memory addresses of an application. You would then need to make a cheat table and save those values with a lua script